# How can I connect to MySQL server from a computer NOT on the network?

Tags: iphone, mysql, remote-access

So there's a lot out there on configuring MySQL to be accessed through a remote computer via localnetwork. I'm trying to connect to it using a device that is NOT on the same network and can't figure out how to do that!

More specifically:

- I have MySQL on a computer running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS at my home
- I want to be able to communicate with the database using an iPhone app (I know how to do the sqlite stuff on iPhone, but I don't know is how to connect to the DB from let's say the other side of the city/configure the database to support this)
- I figure if I can connect to it using another computer not on the network that I'll be able to create a JSON-based service to gather the data, I don't require the iPhone code specifically

I'm assuming I need to set up some username/configure the IP for remote access on the server, but I'm quite the noob when it comes to that. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: There's not (AFAIK) a MySQL driver which you'll be able to deploy with an iPhone app. (You wouldn't want to do that anyhow). So the best bet would be to make a web service which is able to communicate with that database, make it Internet accessible, then write your iPhone app to leverage that web service.

Comment: Providing a data access layer in form of a servlet using Apache/Tomcat on your Ubuntu machine would be one simple idea. Then, your iPhone app can contact the database over the internet.

Comment: Are you looking to write a service that the app will communicate with, or will the app connect directly to the database? If your app is connecting directly, then your question is more suited for serverfault.com. Look into port forwarding and DNS.

Answer (score 1):

May want to create an intermediate layer that handles the connection to the database, it can be useful a web service to connect to MySQL, and from the iPhone you connect to WS.

Comment: Definitely a great suggestion. I ended up using a third party to host my data however. Thanks!